# Problemas com rolagem href para conteudo na mesma página em resoluções menores

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Meu problema é o seguinte.

```
<a href="#saibamais" class="scroll-to">
  Saiba Mais
</a>

<div id="saibamais"></div>

$('a.scroll-to').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 0)}, 600);});
```

Em telas maiores que 992 funciona normalmente, mas ao mudar a resolução de 992 para baixo não funciona mais.

Answer (score 0):

Estranho aqui no site está funcionando perfeitamente.

```js
$('a.scroll-to').on('click', function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: ($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 0)
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
#saibamais{
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#saibamais" class="scroll-to">
  Saiba Mais
</a>

<div id="saibamais">DIV SAIBAMAIS</div>
```

Comment: Funciona no desktop normal, mas quando eu diminuo a tela ele simplesmente não funciona mais,

Comment: Qual navegador está usando? Testei em resolução de **320** por **480** e funcionou normal.

Comment: Testei no firefox, chrome, opera e nada. Também testei diretamente pelo celular e nada. Ele funciona o scroll, mas o efeito de suavidade não aplica.

Comment: Estranho, o que parece ocorrer aí com vc é que a função não executa. Tenta colocar um alert na função depois do **600); alert("testando");** para ver se executa.

Comment: Já fiz, e esta funcionando.

Comment: Cara ta muito estranho isso, se executou o alert então a função está funcionando. Logo o efeito dentro da função deveria funcionar.

Comment: Eu tenho o dom de fazer algo certo dar errado gasheuhiasegh PHP que o diga.

Comment: Este **e.preventDefault()** não é necessário.